# Weakening the Hypothesis in a question involving an invariant set of a differential equation flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, invariance, gradient-descent, gradient-flows

> Consider $f_1,f_2,V\in \scr{C}^1(\Bbb{R}^2;\Bbb{R})$. Suppose that
>
> - (H1) $\langle (f_1,f_2),\nabla V\rangle\leq 0$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$;
> - (H2) $\nabla V(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb{R}^2$.
>
> Suppose that $c\in \mathrm{Image}(V)$. Show that the subset $\Sigma=\{x\in \Bbb{R}^2; V(x)\leq c\}$ is invariant by the flow of
>   \begin{align*}
> p'(s)=(f_1,f_2)^t(p(s))\tag{*}
> \end{align*}
>   i.e., every maximal solution $p(s)$ of $(*)$ that starts in $\Sigma$ remains in $\Sigma$. Can we weaken the hypothesis (H2)?

I was able to easily prove $\Sigma$ invariation, which follows straightfoward from the fact
\begin{align*}
0&\geq \langle (f_1(x(s),y(s)),f_2(x(s),y(s)),(\partial_x V(x(s),y(s)),\partial_yV(x(s),y(s)))\rangle\\
&=\langle (x'(s),y'(s)),(\partial_x V(x(s),y(s)),\partial_yV(x(s),y(s)))\rangle\\
&=\partial_x V(x(s),y(s))\cdot x'(s)+\partial_yV(x(s),y(s)))\cdot y'(s)\\
&=\frac{d\, V}{ds}(x(s),y(s)).
\end{align*}

But, ***can we weaken (H2)***? I insist to review the proof, but each time I read again, it seems I didn't use (H2) at all! Furthermore, all "counterexamples" I can think (functions for $V$ which have critic points, with graphs being saddles or something, and respectively functions $f_1$ and $f_2$) do not work to yield any contradiction!